# count continuous squares from a certain square

Tags: haskell

First of all, I have a board (10 x 10) and a list of specific coordinates, I'm trying to write a function that gets a certain coordinate and a list of specific coordinates and counts how many squares from that list is connected. e.g. let's say I send coordinate `('C', 5)` and list `[('C', 5), ('D', 5), ('D', 6), ('A', 4)]`, the function should return `[('C', 5), ('D', 5), ('D', 6)]` because all of the coordinates are connected. It would seem easy at object orientated programming but I cant figure a way to do that in functional programming.

Comment: Personally I have the impression that this is easier with functional programming. Perhaps it might be better to first design a function signature, and the for example solve a base case (like hardcoding a few examples, looking for patterns).

Comment: My basic idea was to check all for variants and if any succeed then do the same for them e.g. if I'm checking for coord ('C', 5), I would check if coords ('D', 5), ('B', 5), ('C', 4), ('C', 6) are in the list I've got and if they are I would add them to new list and then do the same check for these coords. But didn't yet come up with a way to write that.

Comment: perhaps it is worth first developing a function that takes two coordinates, and returns a `Bool` that specifies if the two are "neighbors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
connected p = map fst . filter ((<=1).snd) . map (liftA2 (,) id (dist p))
          where dist (a,x) (b,y) = max (abs (fromEnum a - fromEnum b)) (abs (y-x))
```

find the elements where max axis distance is less or equal to one, that is the cell itself or immediate neighbors. Perhaps can be written in a shorter way.

```
> connected ('C',5) [('C', 5), ('D', 5), ('D', 6), ('A', 4)]
```

should return

```
[('C',5), ('D',5), ('D',6)]
```

Comment: In a result I need neighbors of ('D', 5) and ('D', 6) and so on. but thank you, that's a good start for me

Comment: but you wrote *"should return [('C', 5), ('D', 5), ('D', 6)]"*.  If you don't need self change `<=1` to `==1`

Comment: `liftA2 (,) id (dist p)` can also be written `id &&& dist p` using `&&&` from `Control.Arrow`, here specialised to the function arrow `(a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)`. But I think point-free is the wrong approach in this case; it seems clearer to me as a list comprehension: ``connected p0 ps = [p | p <- ps, dist p0 p <= 1] where dist (a, x) (b, y) = (a `delta` b) `max` (x `delta` y); delta = fmap abs . ((-) `on` fromEnum)``

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use applicative style to generate the neighborhood then [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) with [`elem`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem). I used [`pred`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pred) and [`succ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ) to handle [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) instances (e.g. `Integer`, and `Char`):

```
filterConn :: (Char,Integer) -> [(Char,Integer)] -> [(Char,Integer)]
filterConn (r,c) = filter (`elem` genNeighborhood)                  
  where
    genNeighborhood = (,) <$> [pred r, r, succ r] <*> [pred c, c, succ c]
```

Furthermore, to obey bounds like a `10x10` board, I would define custom `myPred`, `mySucc` functions that only increment or decrement while obeying the bounds (note there will be duplicates when near a bound):

```
myPred :: (Enum a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
myPred bound val = if pred val >= bound then pred val else val

mySucc :: (Enum a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a 
mySucc bound val = if succ val <= bound then succ val else val
```

Then just drop in `myPred` and `mySucc` to `genNeighborhood` with their respective bounds like so:

```
genNeighborhood = (,) <$> [myPred 'A' r, r, mySucc 'J' r] <*> [myPred 1 c, c, mySucc 10 c]
```

Finally, use `length` to count how many squares are connected:

```
countConn s sqs = length $ filterConn s sqs
```

References: [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors), [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html)